# Aircrack Ch: -1 Issue on Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, aircrack-ng

Currently running [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux), I decided to install [Aircrack-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircrack-ng) and try it out on my own wireless network. So I installed it, and I get an error upon Aireplay that states something along the lines of

> Either patch this, or use the flag --ignore-negative-one

So I used the flag at first. It seems to work, but I can't get a handshake. This might just be me, but I wasn't sure. So I decided to find that patch. I went to Aircrack's website and found it. I followed the instructions and it was fine up until "make". At that point, it outputted:

```
config.mk:199: "WARNING: CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT will be deactivated or not working because kernel was compiled with CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=n. Tools using wext interface like iwconfig will not work. To activate it build your kernel e.g. with CONFIG_LIBIPW=m."
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-ARCH/build M=/home/kyle/Desktop/compat-wireless-2011-05-16 modules
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.38-ARCH/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** modules Error 2
```

What can I do to fix this so I can use Aircrack?

---

`uname -r` outputs "2.6.38-ARCH" (without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the default arch linux kernel (i.e. not a patched one, or one that you've compiled yourself), this would appear to be a bug in the aircrack package, so I would suggest you report it [here](https://bugs.archlinux.org/newtask?project=5&product_category=33&item_summary=%5Baircrack-ng%5D%20PLEASE%20ENTER%20SUMMARY).

I don't know much about aircrack, but based on the error report I think that there are two ways you may be able to fix it yourself.

1. It looks like `CONFIG_CFG80211_WEXT` is a configure option in the patch which you may be able to disable.  However, this might remove important functionality.
2. You could try to compile your kernel with `CONFIG_LIBIPW=m`, as suggested.  This is not as difficult as it sounds, but it does mean that you will need to maintain the kernel yourself instead of relying on pacman to do it for you.  For a guide on this, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Arch_Build_System.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't aircrack require that you have patched drivers for your network card? Have you confirmed that your card has a chipset that is usable ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the Wireless Drivers 'compat-wireless-2011-05-16', I would check that these arew suited to your Wireless Card. You may require MadWiFi Drivers depending. What is your Wireless Card Make/Model?

Comment: Is the answer still relevant considering the question is over 16 months ago?